# if else statement inside (class view = new class)

Tags: c#

I am having a trouble with if else statement in c#, honestly, I am a beginner in this programming language. I know the basic of if else statement but. on this code, I am not sure what should I do.

```
AccountCreateView view = new AccountCreateView()
{
    UserInfo = new UserInfoData()
    {
        if (view.ChangeRefCode == "5")
        {
            TransmissonCode = "0",
            DeliveryCode = "0"
        }
        else
        {
           TransmissonCode = "1",
            DeliveryCode = "1"
        }
    },
    UserLogin = new UserLoginData(),
    UserPassword1 = null,
    UserPassword2 = null,
};
```

if I use if statement inside the `Userinfo = new Userinfo` then my code will turn red.

please help me. i will appreciate any help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If statements are not allowed inside object initialisation blocks. You can only put *expressions* on the right hand side of the `=` operators.

You can use the ternary operator instead:

```
UserInfo = new UserInfoData()
{
    TransmissonCode = view.ChangeRefCode == "5" ? "1" : "0",
    DeliveryCode = view.ChangeRefCode == "5" ? "1" : "0",
};
```

An expression in the form `x ? y : z` where `x` is an expression that evaluates to a `bool` dupe, and `y` and `z` are expressions that evaluates to compatible types, will evaluate to `y` if `x` evaluates to `true`, otherwise `z`.

You can't use an object initialiser for `view`:

```
AccountCreateView view = new AccountCreateView();
view.UserInfo = new UserInfoData() { <see first code snippet> };
view.UserLogin = new UserLoginData();
view.UserPassword1 = null;
view.UserPassword2 = null;
```

Comment: It does not work Sir, the debugger says that this code `TransmissonCode = view.ChangeRefCode == "5" ? "1" : "0",` , Used of unassigned local variable.

Comment: @AlexisAbulenciaVillar I didn't realise that the object initialiser is nested inside the initialiser for `view` as well. In that case, you can't use an object initializer for `view`. Write the initialisations as separate statements.

Comment: How to do that Sir?

Comment: while this is harmless overall, I would like to state that you _are_ in fact running the same `if` logic twice in this answer. If it get's larger than this, it's still wiser to construct the object and follow it with a single `if(condition) {} else {}` to improve performance.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell yes, that’s true.